# Triage queue feeding already closed quesions

Tags: bug, review-queues, triage

Moments ago I've been fed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911493) in the Triage queue:

[image: A screenshot of the question in the review queue.]

When I clicked on "Unsalvageable" (to close it as "primarily opinion based") I've been prompted with a pop-up with only three reasons:

[image: A screenshot of the "Unsalvageable" reasons pop-up.]

I then went to check the question and I noticed it was already closed:

[image: A screenshot of the question.]

That probably explains why I'm getting only those three reasons (and why the pop-up is titled "I am flagging to report this question as" instead of "Why should this question be closed").

Why the system fed me this question when it knew it was already closed (and it knew, since it changed the flagging pop-up)?

Comment: My guess is that it was still open at the time you loaded it in the triage queue, and closed after you loaded it but before you clicked the "Unsalvageable" button. (Your screenshot shows it was closed 1 min ago, which seems to confirm this).